# How to setup storage for my elasticsearch setup on GKE?

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have setup Elasticsearch in single node in GKE how to add storage for my elasticsearch data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a PersistentVolumeClaims (pvc) to the pod. A PersistentVolumeClaim is a request for and claim to a PersistentVolume resource and pods use claims as Volumes. In this following example manifest describes a request for a 30 GiB disk whose access mode allows it to be mounted by one Pod at a time in read/write mode:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: helloweb-disk
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 30Gi
```

You can find more information about PersistentVolumes and PersistentVolumeClaims in Kubernetes [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#top_of_page).

Comment: can you give me complete steps how to do it.

Comment: how about https://medium.com/google-cloud/a-guide-to-deploy-elasticsearch-cluster-on-google-kubernetes-engine-52f67743ee98